# Make SQL command faster

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have this SQL command:

```
SELECT AllServers.steamid, max(AllServers.lastlog) FROM ( 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27105.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27234.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27387.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27408.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27522.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27563.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27612.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27654.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27679.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27698.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27770.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27843.players UNION 
SELECT steamid, lastlog FROM server_27976.players 
) as AllServers GROUP BY AllServers.steamid ORDER BY max(AllServers.lastlog) DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

But this take 10 sec to load.

any tips to make it faster?

Comment: You should consider using just one database and just one table for the players with a column that specifies the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION ALL instead of UNION whenever is possible:

A Union combines the results of two or more queries, however a UNION also verifies if there are duplicate values and removes them in the query results. If you did not know, that aspect can slow down a query. If possible, we always try to avoid it.

That is why UNION ALL is faster. Because it does not remove duplicated values in the query. If there are few rows (let’s say 1000 rows), there is almost no performance difference between UNION and UNION ALL. However, if there are more rows, you can see the difference.

Comment: Thanks the command is now two seconds faster

Comment: This is only possible solution in your case. 

As the next possible optimization was using LIMIT 50 which you have already implemented.

Comment: Time load is same without using LIMIT arg

Comment: If we stick to basics, UNION is faster than JOIN in terms of CPU usage and UNION ALL is better than UNION in your case. Thus this is the best choice as per me.

Comment: Please accept the answer of it makes a difference in your output time